# Where is Hepzibah Mason in Gregory Stone genealogy : ancestry and descendants of Dea. Gregory Stone of Cambridge, Mass., 1320-1917?

Tags: 18th-century, sources, ohio, new-jersey

The American Genealogical-Biographical Index (AGBI) on Ancestry has [this record](https://search.ancestry.com/cgi-bin/sse.dll?indiv=1&dbid=3599&h=528435) which states:

> Name:  Hepzibah Mason
> Volume:    111
> Page Number:   364
> Reference: Gregory Stone gen. Anc. and des. Of Dea. Gregory Stone of Cambridge, Ms. 1320-1917. By J. Gardiner Bartlett. Boston. 1918. (905p.):168

I located [Gregory Stone genealogy : ancestry and descendants of Dea. Gregory Stone of Cambridge, Mass., 1320-1917 on ancestry](https://www.ancestry.com/search/collections/11021) and searched for Hepzibah Mason but am unable to find it.  I checked page 364, I checked the index, I checked her maiden name, Hepziabah Eve, but cannot find any mention of her in the book.

Where can I locate the record in the book referred to by the AGBI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Gregory Stone genealogy; ancestry and descendants of Dea. Gregory Stone of Cambridge, Mass., 1320-1917](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=hvd.32044011695087&view=1up&seq=11) has been digitised by Harvard University, and made available online via the Hathi Trust Digital Library.

---

**Hepzibah Cummings Mason**, eighth child of **Nathanial Mason** and **Sally Stone**, appears on page 168, which corresponds to the '168' at the end of the cited reference in the American Genealogical-Biographical Index.

page 167:
[image: foot of page 167 showing parents of Hepzibah Cummings Mason]

page 168:
[image: top of page 168 showing details of Hepzibah Cummings Mason]

She is also listed in the index on page 874.